# Vue.js not working when const { default: Vue } = require("vue"); is added

Tags: vue.js

I'm taking the introductory phases at the Vue.js.
Everything is finde and all app components are showing until `const { default: Vue } = require("vue");` is added. Then the webpage becomes like on the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyIo3.png)

I have the following code:
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>{{ helloWorld }}</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="app-2">
        <span v-bind:title="message">
            Hold musen over dette, for at se hvordan titlen vil ændre sig!
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="app-3">
        <span v-if="seen">
            Now you see me
        </span>
    </div>

    <div id="app-4">
        <ol>
            <li v-for="todo in todos">
                {{ todo.text }}
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div id="app-5">
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
        <button v-on:click="reverseMessage">Reverse Message</button>
    </div>

    <div id="app-6">
        <p>{{ message }}</p>
        <input v-model="message">
    </div>

    <div id="app-7">
        <ol>
            <!-- Create an instance of the todo-item component -->
            <todo-item
                v-for="item in groceryList"
                b-bind:todo="item"
                b-bind:key="item.id">
            </todo-item>
        </ol>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const { default: Vue } = require("vue");
Vue.component('todo-item', {
    props: ['todo'],
    template: '<li>{{ todo.text }}</li>'
})


var app = new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        helloWorld: 'First vue output!'
    }
});

var app2 = new Vue ({
    el: '#app-2',
    data: {
        message: 'Du har loaded siden den: ' + new Date().toLocaleString()
    }
});

var app3 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-3',
    data: {
        seen: true
    }
});

var app4 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-4',
    data: {
        todos: [
            {text: 'Første punkt'},
            {text: 'Andet punkt'},
            {text: 'Tredje punkt'}
        ]
    }
});

var app5 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-5',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
    },
    methods: {
        reverseMessage: function() {
            this.message = this.message.split('').reverse().join('')
        }
    }
});

var app6 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-6',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
});

var app7 = new Vue({
    el: '#app-7',
    data: {
      groceryList: [
        { id: 0, text: 'Vegetables' },
        { id: 1, text: 'Cheese' },
        { id: 2, text: 'Whatever else humans are supposed to eat' }
      ]
    }
})

var app = new Vue
```

Comment: Why are you not using `import` instead of `require`?

Comment: "Then the webpage becomes like on the picture here" - don't judge by the look, the actual errors that explain the reason are in console. Browsers are unaware of `require`, and they will be unaware of `vue` package if you'll change it to `import`. This is supposed to be done when an app is built, e.g. with Vue CLI. "I'm taking the introductory phases at the Vue.js." - then consider following the official guide which considers Vue CLI the first choice